# Solve diophantine equation with constraints by counting and listing results

Tags: equation-solving, syntax

I need this code to list me and say the total solutions found

```
Reduce[3 x + 2 y == 8800 && 1800 <= x <= 3200 && 
1000 <= y <= 1500 , {x, y}, Integers] /. Or -> List /. And -> List
```

this is an example, there are many more
Thank you

Comment: Why not use `Solve` instead of `Reduce`?

Comment: I find Reduce more versatile

Comment: You can use the `Solve` option `Method->Reduce`

Answer (score 5):

Using [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve) produces the desired results directly:

```
Solve[
    3 x + 2 y == 8800 && 1800<=x<=3200 && 1000<=y<=1500,
    {x,y},
    Integers
] //Length
```

> 167

However, the OP would prefer to use [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce). To have [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce) produce similar output, one needs to change [`SystemOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SystemOptions). Here is some code to do so:

```
Internal`WithLocalSettings[
    old = OptionValue[SystemOptions[], "ReduceOptions"->"DiscreteSolutionBound"];
    SetSystemOptions["ReduceOptions" -> "DiscreteSolutionBound" -> 1000],
    Reduce[
        3 x + 2 y == 8800 && 1800<=x<=3200 && 1000<=y<=1500,
        {x,y},
        Integers
    ] //Length,
    SetSystemOptions["ReduceOptions" -> "DiscreteSolutionBound" -> old]
]
```

> 167

Comment: ok thank you, that simple, I did not see it before, but I just need solutions
how do I do this
1) x = 516, and = 2226
2) x == 518, y = 2223
3) x = 520, y = 2220

Comment: @juanmuñoz There are no solutions for `x = 516, 518, 520`. Define `sol = Solve[...]` (from answer), then the solution with the lowest `x`-value is `MinimalBy[sol, #[[1, 2]] &]`, which is `{x -> 1934, y -> 1499}`.

Comment: an error in writing, I do not understand how to do what you say, then you put the code please, my knowledge is limited and I need it for something punctual